# Making sure this wall is just a partition and not load bearing

Tags: walls, doors, load-bearing, partition

We are considering widening this existing opening and installing double doors.  Is there any chance that this wall is load bearing?

I was going to be overly cautious and put up temporary supports for the trusses above.  But I'm wondering if I'm being paranoid.

Except for a small angle brace toward one end of the opening, the trusses aren't directly connected to the top plate of the, 6' wall below .  There is a gap the same thickness as the ceiling drywall between them.  One of the trusses above the wall is blocked (if that's the correct term) with the next one down.

Construction of the wall is with 2x6s.  I believe there is a double top plate.  A portion of an adjacent wall runs outside.

If this short, 6' wall is indeed load bearing, what is the best way to support the ceiling/roof until the new framing is in place?

[image: attic view]

[image: door opening]

Comment: Those are trusses so they should support themselves.  But you will almost certainly need a building permit and you will almost certainly need your plans signed by an architect or an engineer before they will issue you a permit for such structural changes.  As far as supporting anything while you build, the usual process is to build a temporary wall to suppose the load and then remove it when it's no longer needed.

Comment: The second photo makes it appear that the trusses are set at right angle to the wall (opening) in question. However, the top photo shows the trusses at about a 45 degree angle to the wall. Which is correct? Is this really the correct wall?

Comment: It is the same wall.  The wall is set diagonally from most others in the house and provides the entrance to the adjoining den from the common areas.

Comment: Part 2 (hit enter too soon) The appearance of a right angle is likely a result of my poor digital drawing skills.  The trusses and wall have a 45/135 degree angle between the two.

Comment: How much wider are you going to make it?   In the picture it looks like you have very little extra room without hitting a corner - and then you have to worry about 2 walls being load bearing.   Also why the lack of insulation in that attic?

Comment: Good point about available space before the corners.  The opening will be widened by about 8" total, four on each side.  On the surface, there is about a foot of space available on each side.  Assuming one jack, king, and corner stud on the far ends, there should be at least 6 inches to work with.  Conservatively, that would only leave two to three inches to toe nail the king stud in place. If space is really tight, is there any reason I couldn't just put some spacer blocks between the studs, toe nail on one side of the king stud, and nail through face and spacers to the corner/end stud?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the concerns about potentially load bearing adjacent walls. If I'm only working on this wall which isn't supporting the trusses above, there should be any risk, right?  Regarding the lack of insulation, we have loose fill blown into mesh underneath the roof and between trusses.  The loose fill insulation that you see on the ceiling covers the overhang we have on the front porch.

Answer (score 1):

Not structural.

The 1/2" gap (with the little coupling bracket) between the truss and the diagonal wall, and the straight wall not even being under the truss are clear indications.